# When to answer and when to comment

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

A while ago I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189922/ringing-noise-from-monitor-after-dynamically-generating-html/19190235#19190235) that I knew the answer to.  There wasn't code in the answer so I just made a comment.  The op requested that I add my comment as an answer so he could mark it which I did.  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806738/c-mvc-wrap-view-with-partial) question today where again the answer didn't have code and the answerer declined to put his comment in an answer.  what is the correct way to handle this situation (put the comment that provided the answer into an answer or leave as comment)?

Comment: How is that post an answer to the question?  It doesn't do anything to explain why the described behavior is happening, it just explains how to replicate it.

Comment: that was why I put it as a comment instead of an answer.  I only added it as an answer when requested to.  That is why I am asking the question.  If I should have declined or what is the best practice

Comment: You should have declined.

Comment: This may be ancillary, but there is **no question being asked**. If the question is 'What causes this noise' than the answer is an answer. If the question is 'How do I stop this noise with [jquery]?' then its not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should post an answer when you want to answer the question.

You should post a comment when you want to request information from someone else, or add information that is relevant to a post *but that falls short of answering the question*.  This could be tangential information, a critique of an answer, advice about how to improve the question, or simply information that may be relevant in an answer but that falls short of being a complete answer (this is where your example falls).

Whether or not there is code is irrelevant.  Comments can have code (although they shouldn't have a lot) and answers don't need to have code, if they can answer the question without it.

Whether someone, or the question author, tells you to post an answer also has no bearing.  It is not appropriate to post a comment that doesn't actually answer the question as an answer just because the question author tells you to.  It's often a strong sign that the comment contains a kernel of information likely to be able to create an answer, and it's certainly helpful if you can figure out how to write up an actual answer to the question based on this start and post it for other readers, but it doesn't mean that the original comment is an answer as it stands.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  thank you for the clarification.

Comment: How do you consider passing an answer in the comment when the question actually should be closed example typo etc.  I feel this info is missing in your answer, hence its a good way to help OP without answering off-topic questions.

Comment: @PetterFriberg If the question should be closed, close it, and don't try to answer it.  We close questions because *we don't want them to be answered*, not because we want people to post their answers as comments.

Comment: I like this tough style, but I feel that if you can answer example typo questions with a comment, pass a comment, vote to close. This helps OP and may avoid FGITW answers that will block roomba.

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is an answer to the question(that means that it solves the OP's problem), then write an answer.

If you're not entirely sure that you're right, or if you have only part of an answer, then post it as a comment.